# The direction in which $f(\mathbf{x}) = \sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)}$ is increasing most rapidly

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Find the direction in which the function $f(\mathbf{x}) =
>  \sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)}$ is increasing most rapidly.

The directional derivative at $(a, b)$ is given by

$$\displaystyle (a, b) \cdot \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) = \bigg(\frac{-ax}{\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)}}, \frac{-by}{\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)}}\bigg) $$

That's where I'm stuck. What do I do from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient gives the direction of most rapid increase, so the direction is $$\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) = \bigg(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)}}, \frac{-y}{\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)}}\bigg),$$

which depends on $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you. What's the rate of increase in this case?

Comment: Apply the directional derivative in this $\uparrow$ direction. (as a note, you didn't apply the directional derivative correctly in your question. The dot product of two vectors is a scalar, not a vector).